# Assembly x86 division with DX:AX

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm working with masm and I've encountered a scenario I do not readily understand how to solve, for example:

```
X = (A)/(C*D)
```

If I multiple C*D first, my value is DX:AX and to my knowledge, I cannot use that as a divisor.  If I do division separately as A/C and A/D, I run the risk of losing precision (from the reminders, etc.).  What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: Split it into two cases `DX == 0` and `DX != 0`. The latter case is easy as the quotient is 0. (Make appropriate adjustments if you need support for signed integers)

Comment: I did not consider that DX:AX would naturally be larger than A if DX !=0 and thus the integer division would result in 0; it seems so obvious in retrospect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly note, you can't use a 32-bit number as the divisor in a 16-bit division, but since we're only interested in doing integer division that's not a problem.

There are two cases to consider (for unsigned division):

- `DX == 0`: The result of `C*D` fits in 16 bits so we can proceed as normal using `ax` as the 16-bit divisor.
- `DX > 0` (`DX != 0`): `C*D` is greater than 65335 (`0xFFFF`) and the 16-bit unsigned division of `A` and that number will always be 0 and the remainder is simply `A`.

Or you could do as C and just assume that the result of `C*D` fits in 16 bit. :)